# DateTime Not showing with currentculture format in Datagrid,ListView

Tags: wpf, datetime, listview, mvvm

In WPF I am trying to Bind a date property in a `DataGrid` and I can only sort if it's bound to a `DateTime` property.

The application should show the date in a format corresponding to the user's Region and Language settings.

The issue is that when the date is a `string` property, it shows according to the Region settings, but when the property is bound to a `DateTime` the date format defaults to American rather than the correct region.

So if it's bound to a `string` property the sorting by column doesn't work, and if it's bound to a `DateTime` property, it doesn't convert to the correct region.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's because the binding system uses the culture defined by the [`FrameworkElement.Language`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.language.aspx) property, which doesn't automatically match the current culture (which is a bit silly IMO, but that's the way it is...).

Fortunately there's an easy way around it, you just need to override the metadata for the `Language` property in your application static constructor, [as shown here](http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/04/wpf-tips-1-have-all-your-dates-times.html):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Thomas, This is the exact solution I was expecting.

But Isnt this a bug in .NET Framework.

Comment: This helps, but it only gets us part of the way there.  WPF now figures out when I'm using a different culture like en-GB, but it still does not pick up on changes to region formats (e.g., I changed en-US on my machine to use yyyy-MM-dd, but grids still use MM/dd/yyyy).

Comment: It does display the format correctly in my WPF app now i.e. from MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy but it drops the AM/PM part of my time which I need. I'll keep researching.

Answer (score 2):

The **Localization** sample of the **[Win Application Framework (WAF)](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf)** shows how to solve your issue.

Comment: For those of you hoping to find a different solution in here, they are just using the answer provided by Thomas Levesque.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer (overriding Language metadata) worked for me, but only once for a run of the application. A second call would fail. I replaced it with:

```
var wpfLanguage = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag);
Application.Current.MainWindow.Language = wpfLanguage;
```