# silverlight application wide date

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is there a way to define a application wide format for the dates in Silvelight. So far I've tried to add this code in App_Startup:

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

But all my date binding don't take this into consideration.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Create a string resource in your App.xaml

```
<System.String x:Key="MyDateFormat">dd-MM-yyyy</System.String>
```

And use it as a static resource in your bindings' string format

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding MyDateProperty, StringFormat={StaticResource MyDateFormat}} />
```

I haven't tested this, but that would be my first try.

Comment: this is what I have so far, I was hoping for a universal solution not to modify all my bindings

Answer (score 0):

Try accepted answer from here - [DateTime Not showing with currentculture format in Datagrid,ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630967/datetime-not-showing-with-currentculture-format-in-datagrid-listview).

This works for WPF, you can try it for Silverlight to make it respect your culture.

Comment: thanks, nice idea but unfortunately OverrideMetadata is not in SL4 :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a partial solution for this here: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx

This may not work at the application level though - you may need to apply the solution to various other classes e.g. your child windows.